# Как определить родительский элемент

Tags: javascript, dom

Необходимо на Javascript (кроссбраузерно) определить родительский элемент - `container` для тега `<script src="script.js"></script>` (из самого скрипта - script.js) Учитывая то, что таких конструкций `<div class="container">...</div>` может быть несколько и для каждой нужно определить `container`.

```
<div class="container">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var onViewable = function (result) {
            if (result) {

            }
        }
    </script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: вы хотите взять все теги _script_ с атрибутом _src="script.js"_ и посмотреть у них [parentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode)?

Comment: из самого скрипта - script.js определить его родителя.

Comment: Что то мне подсказывает что это _просто так_ нереально, единственный вариант - перебирать все <script> на странице и исследовать их src и innerText на текст самого скрипта или ссылку на него, которые он так же узнать не сможет, только если они в него явно зашить текст который искать - но тогда смысла нет, проще id сделать для этих элементов и по нему

Comment: Может как-то можно сгенерировать и поставить айди (в script.js) для текущего тега скрипта и по нему найти `parentNode`?

Comment: Те. без проблем можно определить по айди - `document.getElementById('idName').parentNode;`
Но проблема в том что изначально я не могу прописать айдишки, только со скрипта `script.js`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть такое свойство [currentScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript), но оно поддерживается не везде. Соответственно найти родителя просто:

```
var parentElement = document.currentScript.parentNode;
```

Нашелся еще один [трюк](http://www.2ality.com/2014/05/current-script.html), работает во всех браузерах если вы динамически не добавляете элементы `<script>`

```
var parentElement = document.scripts[document.scripts.length - 1].parentNode;
```

Пример:

```html
 <div>Test script 1
 <script>
  document.currentScript.parentNode.style.border = '1px solid blue';
 </script>
 </div>
 <div>Test script 2
 <script>
  document.scripts[document.scripts.length - 1].parentNode.style.border = '1px solid red';
 </script>
 </div>
 <div>Test script 3
 <script>
  document.scripts[document.scripts.length - 1].parentNode.style.border = '1px solid green';
 </script>
 </div>
 <div>Test script 4
 <script>
  document.currentScript.parentNode.style.border = '1px solid green';
 </script>
 </div>
```

Первый и последний `<div>` будут без рамки в IE.

Comment: Internet Explorer Not supported

Comment: @rd2d2 Ой. Это все к той-же задаче с отображением в Экселе?

Comment: `var parentElement = document.scripts[document.scripts.length - 1].parentNode;` последний скрипт в доке... Не пойдёт, тк. скрипт пользовательский, и не известно будет ли он действительно последним. Тем более что их может быть несколько.

Comment: @rd2d2 В каком смысле "пользовательский"? `document.scripts` заполняется последовательно с загрузкой документа. Последний элемент указывает на текущий скрипт. Только подозреваю, что если создавать элементы `<script>`, они могут занимать не последнее место

Comment: Да, действительно работает. Спасибо.