# Использование php в js

Tags: php, javascript

Есть некий скрипт, который находится на одном домене и подключается на внешних сайтах, выполняя необходимые действия. В нем присутствует переменная в которой хранится имя домена исходного сайта, откуда и подключается скрипт.

Всё хорошо работает, но появилась необходимость сделать несколько зеркал главного домена(А возможно позднее потребуется ещё) и соответственно в каждом менять строку с названием домена, довольно трудно, особенно когда они заранее не известны.

Брать домен средствами `JS` не получится, что логично, так как он выполняется на клиенте, потому как вариант появилась идея реализовать вставку значений на стороне сервера при запросе скрипта. Но, если я не путаю, php-скрипт не выполняется в `js-файлах` поумолчанию.

От того вопрос: Каким образом корректнее всего будет получать домен исходного сайта при загрузке скрипта на клиенте?

Comment: Я думаю имеет смысл его в html прописать, а уже JS будет доставать его от туда

Comment: Почему бы вам не брать домен средствами JS через свойство `window.location`?

Comment: Хм. Я кажется только теперь понял что вы хотите знать с какого домена загрузили ваш скрипт. Так?

Comment: @tutankhamun Да, именно так

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделай ему расширение .php и вставь нужный код внутрь. Подключать естественно надо будет как https://domain.com/script.php
Но это не очень красиво. Тебе надо будет сделать реврайт чтоб по запросу
https://domain.com/script.js отдавался твой https://domain.com/script.php

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^js/script\.js$ js/script.php
```

Comment: Можно пример реврайта? Понимаю это делать нужно через `.htaccess`, а знаком я с ним поверхностно.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял и вам нужно найти домен, с которого загружается сам JS скрипт, то тут можно сделать такой фокус:

1. [Находим тег](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/480118/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82/480128#480128), в котором данным скрипт подключается
2. Узнаем адрес скрипта
3. Узнаем домен
4. AJAX-запросом забираем остальные нужные данные

Comment: "Находим тег" не всегда работает так или иначе. `currentScript` не везде поддерживается, а при `scripts.length - 1` ограничение в динамическом добавлении скриптов. Вариант не плохой,я о нем думал, но в моем случае не подходит, увы.

Comment: @BwehaaFox Еще как вариант - уникальное имя скрипта (некоторый суффикс, о котором знает сам скрипт. Если `currentScript` не поддерживается (а сейчас он не поддерживается только в совсем убогих поделках), перебирайте все теги и смотрите на имя

Comment: Как вариант, но увы минутные проблески перфекционизма не позволят мне портить красивые имена скриптов (Которые видно извне), некрасивыми уникальными суффиксами. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯